# How to scan a string in java and then concate it with other string?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

The code is not scanning the second string form user. It just prints 'Hello' second string is not printed.

```
package online_questions;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Add {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    String s = "Hello ";
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    double b = scan.nextDouble();
    String c = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(i+a);
    System.out.println(d+b);
    System.out.println(s + c);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after

```
double b = scan.nextDouble();
```

add

```
scan.nextLine();
```

The methods `nextInt` `nextDouble` etc doens't move to the next line automatically. So you need to call them explicitely.

Answer (score 0):

After reading `double b` there will be a newline character in the buffer. `nexLine()` will read upto new line character `'\0` so that's why your getting empty string simply add`scan.nextLine();`after reading your double

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `nextLine` after `nextDouble`.

```
double b = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine();
String c = scan.nextLine();
```